# MongoDB: How to store credentials safely?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, authentication, credentials

### Context

In my current web application project, I set up a MongoDB database, including server administrator and project users, by means of a number of JavaScript files that are executed with the MongoDB shell.

I can't seem to find a way to handle `root` or user passwords in a safe fashion:

### Problem 1: create users

This is an examplary JavaScript file I use to create a superuser and a project user:

```
use admin

db.createUser(
{
    user: "root",
    pwd: "abc123",
    roles: [
    {
        role: "root",
        db: "admin"
    }]
})

use project_db

db.createUser(
{
    user: "project_admin",
    pwd: "def456",
    roles: [
    {
        role: "dbOwner",
        db: "project_db"
    }]
})
```

Obviously, this file is under version control. How do I go about *not* storing cleartext passwords in there ?!? The [`db.createUser(...)` docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/) explicitely state the cleartext password must be passed (except when using an external user database).

*Seriously ?!?*

### Problem 2: use credentials

I found three ways to pass credentials when accessing the database (to e.g. run the database setup script); none of them works satisfactorily:

#### authenticating on the command line

The `mongo` executable takes corresponding arguments:

```
mongo --username project_admin            \
      --password def456                   \
      --authenticationDatabase project_db \
    < "${path_to_db_build_script}"
```

Problem: The password is visible in e.g. `ps` output. Not acceptable.
Passing `--username project_admin` only fails with `Error: Missing expected field "pwd"`.
Passing `--username project_admin --password` makes `mongo` query the password interactively which obviously prevents automatic script execution - and *automatic* is why this is a script in the first place...

#### authenticating using `~/.mongorc.js`

Taken from [this blog post](http://dbversity.com/password-option-file-in-mongodb):

```
db = connect("localhost:27017/project_db");
db.getSiblingDB("project_db").auth("project_admin", "def456");
```

This does work, but does not seem to provide a way to work with more than one user. There might be an approach to work with one `.js` file *per user* and/or `.js` file templates, but once there is any complexity involved there, those files should be under version control - and that brings us back to the same problem as for creating users.

#### authenticating using code

In theory, it should also be possible to use [`db.auth(...)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.auth/) to authenticate within the script.
In practice, this just seems an epic fail to me:

This works, but stores credentials in code:

```
db.auth("project_admin", "def456")
```

This works using a JSON doc; also stores credentials in code:

```
db.auth({ user: "project_admin", pwd: "def456" })
```

`db.auth(...)` does have a `digestPassword` parameter which is largely undocumented, but the name suggests it is meant to indicate the password is passed in some encrypted / hashed / salted / whatever fashion.

This would allow storing the `.js` scripts in version control with non-cleartext passwords; not ideal, but definitely better than cleartext. However, this simply *does not work*, i.e. fails with `Error: Authentication failed.`

For starters, I would assume setting `digestPassword` to `false` is appropriate when passing the password in cleartext; however, this fails (BUG #1 ?):

```
db.auth({ user: "project_admin", pwd: "def456", digestPassword: fails })
```

whereas this works (WTF ?!?):

```
db.auth({ user: "project_admin", pwd: "def456", digestPassword: true })
```

Setting the `mechanism` to `PLAIN` fails with `Error: Missing expected field "mechanism"`, despite the field clearly being there (BUG #2 ?), no matter if `digestPassword` is `true` or `false`:

```
db.auth({ user: "project_admin", pwd: "def456", digestPassword: true, mechanism: "PLAIN" })
```

Setting the `mechanism` to the default `SCRAM-SHA-1` seems to expose the same bug as above; this fails:

```
db.auth({ user: "project_admin", pwd: "def456", digestPassword: fails, mechanism: "SCRAM-SHA-1" })
```

whereas this works:

```
db.auth({ user: "project_admin", pwd: "def456", digestPassword: true, mechanism: "SCRAM-SHA-1" })
```

Encrypted / hashed / digested / whatever passwords can be obtained by starting the `mongo` shell as `root`, e.g.

```
mongo admin -u root -p abc123
```

and running `db.system.users.find()` which returns something like this:

```
  ...
{
    "_id": "project_db.project_admin",
    "user": "project_admin",
    "db": "project_db",
    "credentials":
    {
        "SCRAM-SHA-1":
        {
            "iterationCount": 10000,
            "salt": "WnKFmGs3BTbmkbUWi0RPnA==",
            "storedKey": "EEIMqBEMUUOpoR3i3pgKz0iRumI=",
            "serverKey": "HsSOxujNODlKcRiEdi1zkj83MRo="
        }
    },
    "roles": [
    {
        "role": "dbOwner",
        "db": "project_db"
    }]
}
  ...
```

Using any of the three hashes (?) from the output as password with `digestPassword` `true` or `false` fails. Without looking into the sources, I can only assume that there is some `sha1(password + salt)` relationship with the `credentials` above, but there seems to be no documentation whatsoever and the presumed bugs my attempts so far have exposed do not exactly encourage pursuing this any further.

#### custom approach

There might be a way to run JavaScript in `~/.mongorc.js` that takes the current username (from where ?) and looks up the password from an external source. But why would I have to implement credentials management for a supposed database solution ?

### Questions:

1. How do people handle credentials when working with MongoDB ?
2. My experience with MongoDB so far has been so abyssmally bad that, considering MongoDB is being sold for production purposes, it seems wise to first search for the cause on my side. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong ? Are my expectations unjustified ? Do MongoDB users not care about password safety ?

I would greatly appreciate if someone could share their approaches and experiences.

Comment: Hi @ssc, did you managed to find a way? This is exactly what I am looking at the moment and can't find anything.

Comment: @Lukino: Nope, sorry. Due to this - and many, many other issues - I stopped trying to use MongoDB: I still have a feeling I'm misunderstanding something fundamentally, but AFAICT, the hype around MongoDB is not justified; at least it wasn't when I asked the question 2 years ago.

Comment: Well, I managed to hack it a little bit, so Mongo setup isn't totally insecure - mainly having passwords in cleartext... 

Basically you create a user `db.createUser(...)` using fake password and then you update his credentials to already hashed one in a way `db.system.users.updateOne({user: "user", {$set: {credentials: "..."}}})`. 

Not perfect way to do this, but works for me. This will make me less worried to have unencrypted password on gitlab/chef server (although for latter one there is an encrypted data bag, which I used till now, but I am trying to not to use it)

Answer (score 3):

You could prepare your script in version control and assume a local file called `password.file` with restricted read permissions containing the password in clear text.

You can then launch the script like this:

```sh
cat password.file | mongo -u <USERNAME> < myscript.js
```

This makes the Mongo shell read the password from stdin, and has the benefit of keeping the password out of version control and out of `ps` output.

Probably a better solution is to use [x509 certificates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-x509-client-authentication/) for the script, or moving to Kerberos for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`load`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/load/) to load a file with the `connect` command:

```
touch conn.js
chmod 600 conn.js
vim conn.js
# db = connect('localhost/mydb', 'myuser', 'pword');
vim myscript.js
# load('conn.js')
# db.coll.count()
mongo --nodb < myscript.js
```

This way you can have multiple connection files in safety and excluded from version control.

Answer (score -5):

I assume you are using node.js

so the basic approach would be  to do an application side encryption i.e. encrypt in your app code the fields such as passwords before saving it to mongoDB.

how you do it ?

you can use a node.js package called `bcrypt`.

To install bcrypt use the following command: `npm install bcrypt –save-dev.`

Then you can write a function on Save operation which will encrypt the fields you want before saving them to MongoDatabase.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/project_db');

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', function(err){
    console.log('connection error', err);
});

db.once('open', function(){
    console.log('Connection to DB successful');
});

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userSchema= new Schema({
    name:String,
    password:String
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

userSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    var user = this;
    if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

    bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function(err, salt){
        if(err) return next(err);

        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash){
            if(err) return next(err);

            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});

var testSample = new  User({
    name: "admin",
   password: "password1234"
});

testSample.save(function(err, data){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else console.log ('Sucess:' , data);
});
```

The other option you have is to configure some security at the Database level itself. well that's something huge so i cannot really summarize it here.

hope this link will be helpful for you : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/security/

Comment: I don't really understand what you are doing there, but I can't help but get the impression you have fundamentally misunderstood my question: For starters, I'm not using node.js. Furthermore, I'm not talking about application users, but database users. Also, managing the users of a service like a database by means of an ORM does not appropriate to me. Last not least, your approach does not solve the actual problem as you still store credentials in code. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This doesn't address how to make a connection to the database and securing the credentials "at rest" and at the cmdline.